# Webassembly missing _free function cannot free memory

Tags: webassembly

I am passing an array of data to a WebAssembly function:

```
 const input = Module._malloc(size);
 [fill up buffer...]
 Module.HEAP8.set(size, input);
 Module.someCall(input);
```

And this works. Indeed, _malloc is part of the Module. However, the free function is not. Tried to use `DEFAULT_LIBRARY_FUNCS_TO_INCLUDE` and `EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS`. Also try to implement my own free function:

```
EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
void free(void *ptr) {
  free(ptr);
}
```

Compiling with:

```
emcc -O3 -s WASM=1 test.c -o test.js
```

But no luck. Either `_free` is not found in the module. Either, by defining the above function in my C code, the function is present in Module but it does nothing, I eventually run out of memory. Doc is sparse on that suject.

Does anybody know how to retrieve the free function which actually free my buffers?

Comment: So it seems when compiling without `-O3` the `_free` function is present and does actually work. I need to find a way to tell the compiler to compile with Optimization and keep `_free` then.

Answer (score 2):

You can always add the function "_free" to the compile parameter `-s EXPORTED_FUNTIONS` to be sure it is available as an export in the WASM.

Comment: `emcc -s 'EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=["_free"]'`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you didn't compile the code correctly.

Here is my sample.

Create a **test.c** file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <emscripten.h>

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
int add(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
uint8_t* create(int width, int height) {
  return malloc(width * height * 4 * sizeof(uint8_t));
}

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
void destroy(uint8_t* p) {
  free(p);
}
```

Compile the code:

```
emcc test.c -O2 -s WASM=1 -Wall -s MODULARIZE=1 -o test.js
```

Create a **index.js** file:

```
const Module = require('./test.js');
const wasm = Module({wasmBinaryFile: 'test.wasm'});
wasm.onRuntimeInitialized = function() {
    console.log(wasm._add(40, 40));
    let mem = wasm._create(100, 100);
    wasm._destroy(mem);
    console.log("Done");
};
```

Run it in Node.js:

```
node index.js
```

Run it on a web page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var wa_add, wa_create, was_destroy, wasm;

        function add() {
            let int1 = document.getElementById('int1').value;
            let int2 = document.getElementById('int2').value;
            if (wa_add) {
                document.getElementById('result').innerText = wa_add(parseInt(int1), parseInt(int2));

                // API test
                if (wa_create && was_destroy) {

                    let canvas = document.getElementById('image');
                    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    var image = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    const p = wa_create(canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    wasm.HEAP8.set(image.data, p);
                    // Do something for the image buffer.
                    was_destroy(p);
                }


            } else {
                document.getElementById('result').innerText = parseInt(int1) + parseInt(int2);
            }
        }

        if (Module) {
            wasm = Module({
                wasmBinaryFile: 'test.wasm'
            });
            wasm.onRuntimeInitialized = function () {
                document.getElementById('anim-loading').style.display = 'none';
                wa_add = wasm._add;
                wa_create = wasm._create;
                was_destroy = wasm._destroy;
            };
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Yes I did exactly what you did (Except for the `MODULARIZE` option). Have you verified that the call to `destroy` actually frees memory? Apparently, It does not for me, because it runs out eventually.